# A Get method for an API, with three modes

Tags: c#, api

Is this good way to create a get API method with different service methods?
Based on the `scope` parameter, it decides what service method in the API to call.

Enum:

```
    enum scopeValue
    {
          None,
          GetAll, 
          GetWithDetails 
    };
```

API:

```
   public class WorkItemController : BaseController
    {
        private IWorkItemService workItemService;

        public WorkItemController(IWorkItemService workItemService)
        {
            this.workItemService = workItemService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>> Get(int id, string scope = "None")
        {
            scopeValue choice;

            Enum.TryParse(scope, out choice);

            if (choice == scopeValue.None)
            {
                return await workItemService.Get(id);
            }
            else if (choice == scopeValue.GetAll)
            {
                return await workItemService.GetAll();
            }
            else if (choice == scopeValue.GetWithDetails)
            {
                return await workItemService.GetAllWithDetails();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is real code in progress. I am still not sure about design api so I am asking if this is good aproach. But its working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's think about what your possible URIs would look like.

```
http://example.com/WorkItem?id=5
http://example.com/WorkItem?id=5&scope=GetAll
```

That's not how I'd expect the API to work. Typically, calling the resource without an `id` will return all of them.

```
// returns all work items
http://example.com/WorkItem

// returns work item by id
http://example.com/WorkItem/5
```

And then, to get the details for an item, we add an action to the end of the URI.

```
// returns details for specified item
http://example.com/WorkItem/details/5
```

To get the last part, you'll need to wire up a custom route, but it's not that difficult to do. You can then overload the `Get` methods to implement this. It's a much cleaner API to work with and, honestly, results in a much cleaner & maintainable controller.

---

I take it back, you won't need a custom route. MVC comes "out of the box" with a `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route, so for the `Detail` route, all you need to do is create the proper method.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>> Details()
```

And

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>> Details(int id)
```

Will give you routes that look like this.

```
http://example.com/WorkItem/Details
http://example.com/WorkItem/Details/5
```

Comment: Updated my answer. You shouldn't even need a custom route.

Comment: So {action} is name of api method ? Can I also call 'h ttp://example.com/WorkItem/detail' ? So without Id and with action. If I want to have 2 get methods without paramaters

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to specify a custom route. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Comment: Actually, you won't need a custom route. I screwed the order up. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I this good way to...

**Short answer: no**

**Longer answer**

One of the reasons is clearly that a user will have pass some value for `id` although it wouldn't be needed e.g if the passed in `scope != "None"`.

Another thing is, that you never really check the result of `Enum.TryParse()` which returns a `bool` for a purpose. If this `public` method is called by passing e.g `"none"` or `null` nothing is done without comunicating the reason to the caller like e.g throwing an exception.

If you still want to go this way, I would like to suggest that you check for `null` of `scope` and also use this overloaded [`Enum.TryParse(string, bool, out TEnum)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which adds the ability to ignore the case of the passed in string.

The very minimum should be to return early if `Enum.TryParse()` returns `false`.

Comment: is it pissible to do this wothout tryParse?  Send enum insted of string.

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor Get method and have something as below. This will look more cleaner and easier to maintain.

```
// This makes more sense to me. Because API states that 
// caller will get one object of WorkItemDto if it provides the ID.
public async Task<WorkItemDto> Get(int id)
{
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>> GetAll()
{
}

// so on ..
```

Comment: but I still need GetAl()l and GetAllWithDetails(). So I must have some enum as parameter of second function.